# Pandas: fill column based on data in different column

Tags: python, pandas

I Have the following Dataframe:

```
test_df['A'] = [100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100]
test_df['B'] = [100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0]
```

What I want to achieve is a new column C where if I iterate on column B and I find a 100 value then I want to forward fill until the column A has 100 value in it. Which will result in a column like this:

```
test_df['C'] = [100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100]
```

This can be achieved by a simple iteration of all values with something like the following:

```
test_df['C'] = 0
is_valid_row = False
for index, row in test_df.iterrows():
    if (row['B'] == 100):
        is_valid_row = True
    if (is_valid_row == True and row['A'] == 100):
        row['C'] = 100
    else:
        is_valid_row = False
```

I wanted to ask if there is any more efficient way to achieve the same result with pandas or numpy

Comment: What if B has a cell with 100, but the corresponding A cell does not?

Comment: There should not be that case in the dataset, but lets assume in that case C will be 0

Answer (score -2):

You can use the apply method.

```
def my_func(input):
   #do whatever

test_df['B'] = test_df['A'].apply(my_func)
```

You obviously have to fill it in with your own code...

Comment: `I wanted to ask if there is any more efficient way to achieve the same result with pandas or numpy` and this doesn't answer the question, because `apply` is sometimes worse than a for loop.

Comment: Guess it depends on your definition of "efficient"

Comment: @SuperStew There is a pretty agreed-upon notion of efficiency when it comes to NumPy/Pandas problems.